# Submitting OG built-in actions used in mobile app for FB approval

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on mobile (Android/iOS) app, which will integrate with FB and have a Like action. 
Rather than duplicating action as a custom one, I've opted for using [built-in Like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/). Normal procedure for native apps seem to be providing screenshots. However, built-in apparently are special case. While clicking submit I've get red box with following warning:

> Built-in Action Types require that you provide instructions for using
>   your app's Open Graph integration as your Open Graph Test User in a
>   functioning test environment. Failure to provide a functioning test
>   environment will result in rejection of your Action Type.

How am I suppose to provide *"a functioning test environment"* for an unreleased mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just provide the screenshots if you have an unreleased mobile app, even if you're using the built-in action types.